# Ant task to compile PHP templating files into static HTML pages

Tags: php, ant

Our current site is broken down into various easy to work with PHP includes that are brought together using one of those nifty PHP templating libraries.

We currently use an Ant build to optimize most of our front-end code in regards to concatenating, minifying and image optimization. What we would like to do is add an additional Ant task that will parse the PHP template files and output static HTML pages into our build folder.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

A very basic example below of what I would like to achieve:

PHP template before build

```
<?php 
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/tpl/basic-template.php');

    startblock('title');
        echo 'Test page';
    endblock();

    startblock('content');
        include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/incl/content-fragment.php');
    endblock();
?>
```

Is it possible through an Ant task to create the static HTML page of the above as so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This paragraph was the contents of content-fragment.php</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you need provide a real example of what you have and what you need. I don't understand your requirements.

Comment: The problem I see is, that templates are usually not static, thus I suspect compiling in static HTML files will not work as you expect.

Comment: @oers I have added a basic example of what I am trying to do. Hope this clarifies my question a bit.

Comment: @KingCrunch In this instance we can assume that the templates will always be static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [Ant Get](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/get.html) task by hosting files in a build server that is running [apache](http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi):

```
<get src="http://buildserver/index.php" dest="app/index.html"/>
```